# How to hide ONLY this notice "You cannot add another (product) to your cart" with CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

How to hide ONLY this notification "You cannot add another (product) to your cart" from woocommerce with CSS? If I use this CSS code then all notifications are hidden but other notifications are useful.

```
ul.woocommerce-error,.page-id-6 .woocommerce-notices-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't know woocommerce, so I can't really answer that. As Fmerco has answered, there's no way in CSS to apply style based on the content of an element. And from your question I infer that you have examined the classes of the element. Perhaps, as alternative, there is an attribute and value unique to that kind of notification (data-*, or other), in that case you could put [attribute="value"] in your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to apply such logic with the sole help of the CSS.

Comment: Oh okay, what kind of code should I insert to function.php?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
* this code may help to unset specific notice
*/

function remove_added_to_cart_notice()
{
    $notices = WC()->session->get('wc_notices', array());

    foreach( $notices['success'] as $key => &$notice){
        if( strpos( $notice, 'You cannot add another (product) to your cart' ) !== false){
            $added_to_cart_key = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
    unset( $notices['success'][$added_to_cart_key] );

    WC()->session->set('wc_notices', $notices);
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product','remove_added_to_cart_notice',1);
```